# Difference merge response in gitlab pipeline compared to local

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to automtaically merge pushes to master to the develop branch.
For that reason, the following .gitlab-ci.yml has heen created.

```
sync_master:
  stage: sync
  image: bitnami/git
  variables:
    GIT_CHECKOUT: "true"
    GIT_DEPTH:  1
  script:
    - git config user.name "CI Pipeline"
    - git config user.email "ci@pipeline"
    - git checkout develop
    - git pull origin master --no-ff
  rules:
    - if: CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == "master" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
```

Now it reproduces the following error:

```
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Adding `--allow-unrelated-histories` makes this error disappear, but generates a lot of conflict errors. Which are not there, I actually tested the merge locally as well. Here there were no errors and the merge happened as extended.

```
git checkout develop
git fetch develop
git reset --hard origin/develop
git pull origin master --no-ff
```

So it seems there is a different version active in the gitlab pipeline. However I checked it with `git log`. Both on gitlab pipeline as local, it shows exactly the samen last commit.

Comment: Locally you are resetting to `origin/develop` but I can't tell if you are on the same commit on the CI server. Maybe print out the commits in the CI script with `git rev-parse develop` and `git rev-parse origin/develop`, and `master` / `origin/master` as well just to be sure.